# liquibase agnostic insert with sequence

Tags: liquibase

I want to create a new insert changeset in liquibase using a sequence to populate the id field. Is there any way to make it database agnostic for Oracle an Postgres?

This is the oracle way:

```xml
    <changeSet author="XX" id="XX">
        <insert tableName="NODO_MENU">
            <column name="ID" defaultValueSequenceNext="SEQ_NODO_MENU" />
            <column name="CODIGO" value="ABC" />
            <column name="ORDEN" value="0" />
        </insert>
        <rollback>
            <delete tableName="NODO_MENU">
                <where>CODIGO = 'ABC'</where>
            </delete>                       
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
```

It doesn´t work in postgres:
[Failed SQL: INSERT INTO public.NODO_MENU (ID, CODIGO, ORDEN) VALUES (SEQ_NODO_MENU.NEXTVAL, 'ABC', '0')]

To make it work in postgres I changed the column tag to:

```
<column name="ID" valueComputed="nextval('SEQ_NODO_MENU')" />
```

How can i write this changeset to make it work in Oracle an Postgress?

Answer (score 0):

You can write two separate changesets. One for Postgres, one for Oracle.

Just add corresponding `dbms preConditions` to them.

As such:

```
<changeSet author="XX" id="XX_oracle">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <dbms type="oracle"/>
    </preConditions>
    <!-- your logic for Oracle-->
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="XX" id="XX_postgres">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <dbms type="postgresql"/>
    </preConditions>
    <!-- your logic for Postrgres-->
</changeSet>
```